# Making a single node using multiple nodes

Tags: node-editor, customization

Is there a way to reduce a set of nodes to a single customized node. I am needing to put some mathematical expression and when I do it using the node editor (in animation node) the whole tree looks quite clumsy and it becomes quite unreadable. 
[image: the node tree]

[image: make group]

Comment: Select desired nodes and press `Ctrl`+`G`

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/groups.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple. All you have to do is to create a group from the nodes.

Simple example:

Say you have some fancy node setup:

[image]

To group these nodes, select those you want to group (press <kbd>B</kbd> to border select ). Then in the nodes menu select Node > Make Group (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

After having created the group, connect the input sockets you want to have as input (here the color to diffuse shader):

[image]

To get out of your group click on the little up arrow at the bottom:

[image]

(Or press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key)

*Et voilà*, you have a fancy shader:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: I am able to get the option of make group for materials node editor but not able to get it for the animation node editor.

Comment: I have added the relevant image